# TrueNAS SMB Share Inaccessible by NetBIOS Name

Tags: samba, truenas, netbios

I'm currently working on a TrueNAS server to create a file share for a computer lab, and I've got everything working except for being able to connect to the share via it's custom NetBIOS name.

I can connect to the share via \\TRUENAS or its direct IP, but I'd prefer that the NetBIOS name that I had set be what students can connect to and see.

Everything on the console side looks correct. Hostname, NetBIOS name, NetBIOS alias, and Kerberos principal are all set to what I want to appear. Machine is domain-joined and I can see it in Active Directory and moved it to an appropriate OU. Machine also has a static IP configured.

However, something that I've noticed just today is that I cannot ping the server via its machine name, only its IP. I get a destination host unreachable when trying to ping its machine name, even though it's clearly on network, can talk to DNS, etc.

I'm not even sure where to begin to troubleshoot and naturally, I have a handful of other projects to work on prior to the start of next semester, so I sadly have little time to dedicate to poking around... Any help would be absolutely appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check it's DNS record, and make sure the workstations are using your internal DNS server, not a public DNS server.